# Insults in the gemarah

Tags: talmud-gemara, rabbis, derech-eretz-manners, middos-character-traits

Why do tanaim and amoraim use disparaging terms (bavlai tipshai, for instance) or insults when talking with one another. If there is something positive to be learned from this behavior why is it no longer employed?

I have heard many attempts to explain this away, none that are satisfactory.

Comment: Rishonim did it all the time too. (Ramban and Baal HaMaor; Raavad on the Rambam)

Comment: @DoubleAA Nekudas Hakesef on the Taz. IIRC The Shach (who IIRC was in his 20s when he wrote the Nekudas Hakesef on the Taz who was in his 70s) wrote that "if he had a brain his his skull, he wouldn't have written this."

Answer (score 14):

[Chavos Yair (152)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=857&pgnum=166) discusses a number of these cases.

In some of them, he says, the person delivering the insulting remark is the other one's teacher; the halachah is indeed that if a teacher sees that his students aren't applying themselves properly to their studies, he should "get angry at them and insult them verbally" to spur them to correct behavior ([Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh De'ah 246:11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&pgnum=139)).

In others, an apparent insult is in fact a complimentary statement. As an example, in several places where Rav Sheshes says of Rav, "He must have been falling asleep when he said this," Chavos Yair says that it means just that: it would be impossible for a great Torah scholar like Rav to have made a mistaken statement except under such conditions.

And then there are various other types that he lists. (One that I don't understand is his treatment of the expression תרדא\תדורא in a few places: he says that the people who made these statements were "their colleagues and greater than them, so that they didn't mind at all" - yet in one of his examples, in Bava Metzia 20b, the person so addressed does seem to have minded, and there were consequences.)

Comment: awesome, thank you, I'm going to check this source out.

Answer (score 7):

The Chafetz Chaim in the B'er Mayim Chaim ([8:23](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14233&st=&pgnum=155)) wrote that they were not trying to disparage their colleague in a personal way.  Their intent was to undermine the authority of one making a ruling that was still subject to debate.  The accuser was concerned for the negative consequences of those who followed the statement as law.

Comment: can you explain this further? why was such language ok to use to accomplish that goal? Why do we no longer employ this kind of technique in torah learning?

Comment: @Moshe some do :)

Comment: @Moshe, I'm afraid Shmuel is right.  Many disparage talmidei chachamim to "save" others from their "crum" hashkafos.  But the real answer is- can we do so 100% leshem shamayim?  perhaps those mentioned above knew they could.  Although i'm not sure how their intent circumvents the laws.  I don't know to what extent we apply es laasos, but that could be a factor.

Comment: I think we need some concrete documentation, this seems to only be speculation

Comment: I once attended a gemoro shiur in which the magid shiur said something like, "Rovo said, 'My dear Abaye, you are mistaken ...etc.' and Abaye replied in similar respectful tones.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok indeed, but the question refers to those cases that clearly use derogatory language.

Comment: @Moshe: speculation on what count?

Answer (score -6):

While there are many ways to justify their behavior post factum as brought in the other answers, it seems that their behavior wasn't Halachic at all.

The simplest proof to that is that none of those behaviors was brought to Halacha by the later Poskim as an Asmachta (see Meforshim on Rambam's original [T"T 4,5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Torah_Study.4.5?lang=he&with=Commentary&lang2=he)), in other words Rambam didn't say "one must reprimand and shame his students just as R' X did it in the Gemmorah".

---

<sub>Note: It is important to stress that those acts are not just light misbehaviors but a clear transgression of the Deorayso Mitzvah of [אונאת דברים](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%AA_%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D#%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9F) - Rambam 251, Chinuch 338, Tur 228. Even if we say that they held some lenient opinions, Sofek Deorayso should be more stringent, and there's also a Mar'is Ayn - the fact that the question was asked shows that it is perceived as a transgression.</sub>

Comment: -1 As previously discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14875/9682), they either weren’t insults or were halachically correct in insulting them.

Comment: @DonielF Says who? Only two Poskim were brought to justify and they weren't thorough. If their acts were Halachic they would be brought as Asmachtot. As nobody did it  - No Posek saw those insults as Halachical. Find me one to disprove.

Comment: @DonielF BTW Why wasn't that answer accepted? It seems others think it just donesn't cut.

Comment: I don’t need to find a Posek for you to disprove - Alex already did. Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh Deah 246:11: חייב לכעוס עליהם ולהכלימם בדברים כדי לחדדן ועל זה אמרו זרוק מרה בתלמידים.

Comment: Are you seriously arguing on the Shulchan Aruch because a random guy on the Internet didn’t award him a check mark? Maybe he just forgot.

Comment: @DonielF You misunderstand me. I claimed that no Posek brings the cases as Asmachtah. In other words, neither Rambam or S"A say **"להכלימם... כמו שעשה ר"א"** and the like. Show me a Posek that brings those behaviors as examples.

Comment: Why does he need to bring the stories when he explicitly quotes זרוק מרה בתלמידים? He doesn’t need to say “like so-and-so did” because he can say “the Gemara explicitly says to act like this.” What benefit is there to quoting additional sources?

Comment: @DonielF Ask yourself - is the point of your comments to defend your approach or to find the truth? Because it just proves my other claim about the way of Judaism that everybody's after proving themselves right instead of seeking the truth. I understand your point completely but you fail to understand mine. So what's the point of arguing? Blindly relying on Poskim without understanding underlying mechanisms is not for me.

Comment: The Shulchan Aruch quotes a Gemara and is in line with the Tannaim and Amoraim in question. You not only are saying that those Rabbis are halachically wrong, but you also have never reinterpreted that Shulchan Aruch to indicate anything close to what you're saying. If you want to discuss the concept of Emunas Chachamim in more detail, I suggest we take this discussion over [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62150/9682).

Comment: Torah shebal peh. The mesorah they had written down. We have mesorah on how great the amoraim were. We know how great the chafetz chaim was. He would never hurt someones feelings. For sure the amoraim wouldn't ever chas vishalom violate aninus devarim. They're not to paired with your typical joe.